# Wildfly 9 Hibernate using H2 database instead of MS SQL Server

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, wildfly, h2

My Java EE application was working just fine, but suddenly it refused to do anything with database. On redeployment, I got following stacktrace:

```
12:08:54,001 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Table "USERS" not found; SQL statement:
select userentity0_.id as id1_7_, userentity0_.password as password2_7_, userentity0_.username as username3_7_ from users userentity0_ [42102-173]
(...)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "USERS" not found; SQL statement:
select userentity0_.id as id1_7_, userentity0_.password as password2_7_, userentity0_.username as username3_7_ from users userentity0_ [42102-173]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
(...)
```

I've noticed strange thing here. From stacktrace it seems, that **it's using H2 database driver** (or something), **instead of Microsoft SQL Server**, as it was before. I don't remember changing anything with database recently, it just exploded out of nowhere.

I found that similar question has already been asked here:
[Wildfly mysql instead of h2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621196/wildfly-mysql-instead-of-h2)
But answer posted there is not satisfying me - I'd like for it to work without datasource, just storing all database configuration in `persistence.xml` and keep it application-server independent (as much as possible).

My `persistence.xml` file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!-- some classes in <class> tags -->        
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://<my Azure database server>:1433;database=<db name>;user=<username>;password=<pass>;encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect"/>
            <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What should I change to make it work again with MS SQL Server database?

Comment: Did you change the JPA subsystem to use the MS SQL JNDI name?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Could you be a little bit more verbose? I'm not sure that do you mean. All my DB-related settings are in `persistence.xml` presented above.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I'll post an answer now that I'm reading it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [define](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/DataSource+configuration) the MS SQL data source in the container. [Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/jamezp/3d3fe3bf57fe99ea91c1) of adding a PosgreSQL driver and data source.

Then in your `persistence.xml` you definet he JTA data source:

```xml
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MSSqlDS</jta-data-source>
```

This is required since you want the container to manage your transactions. As far as I know you can't define the connection parameters with JTA.

The reason you're seeing H2 being used is by default it's using the `ExampleDS` which is the default data source. You could set your own data source as the default data source and leave off the `<jta-data-source/>` from your `persistence.xml` as well.

```
/substem=ee/service=default-bindings:write-attribute(name=datasource, value="java:jboss/datasources/MSSqlDS")
```

That would set the default data source, `java:comp/DefaultDataSource`, be your defined data source.

Comment: Could you provide an actual persistence.xml for posgreSQL driver? It could help me a lot thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need anything specific in the `persistence.xml` for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Then how do I tell my project(development) not to use h2 in-memory, but to use PostgreSQL for its datasource? I have a posted question, you might consider to answer it. Thanks. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628608/how-to-use-a-database-as-your-database-source-in-jpa/39629206